# Ways to retrive deleted iMessages on iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages

This may be a popular question, but I have not seen a very satisfying answer for it. It is unfortunate when one accidentally deletes iMessages because all of the history of that message is gone, and there appears to be no way to get it back on the device itself.

Are there existing apps that would recover messages onto the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of apps that can recover messages from your iPhone. If you accidentally deleted messages off your iPhone, you would need to restore the iPhone from your most recent iCloud or iTunes backup.

The restore will bring back all the SMS/iMessages that were present on your iPhone at the time of the backup itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to be able to access those deleted iMessages

1. If you have a mac computer with the Messages application set up, you can view the messages in that app after deleting them from your phone. This will only work for iMessages and not text messages.
2. You can restore your iPhone to a previous iCloud or iTunes backup to view the messages on your phone again.