# Restoring older iCloud backup

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, restore

I recently deleted some important text messages and the only way I think I can get them back is to restore from iCloud backup (in my case the restore deleted text messages option is not possible).
I would like to erase / restore my phone but it has been a few days since they were deleted and the latest iCloud backup would not contain the messages I need. I would need to restore from a week or two week old backup. Is anything like this possible with iCloud? I assume they incrementally backup the data so restoring from a specific date should not be a big deal.

Is this possible?

Comment: That should work : https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204184#icloud you should see all the backups from icloud.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to retrive deleted iMessages on iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75631/ways-to-retrive-deleted-imessages-on-iphone)